# Installing custom package which depends on other custom package

Tags: r, package, dependency-management

I have a utilities package `foo`, and have developed another package `bar` which calls functions in `foo`.

`foo` is available on a URL (not Github or any such service) as source files. I install/update it using

```
install.packages("//mywebsite.com/foo",
                 repos = NULL,
                 type = "source")
```

I now want to share `bar` with others. I've read the [`devtools` page on dependencies](https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/blob/master/vignettes/dependencies.Rmd) and understand I merely have to add a `Remotes` section to my DESCRIPTION file.

However, the example for a URL-based remote dependency is:

```
# URL
Remotes: url::https://github.com/hadley/stringr/archive/master.zip
```

What concerns me here is that the example uses a .zip file, but the package `foo` is only available as a raw source directory.

Will this work? Can I simply use

```
Remotes: url:://mywebsite.com/foo
```

Or does this only work with zipped files?

I notice the following example, for local packages, does not have an extension (`Remotes: local::/pkgs/testthat`), which makes me hopeful it's representing a source directory and that therefore that'll also work for URLs, but am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `remotes::install_url` requires a .zip, .tar, or .tar.gz, and that's likely what would be called to install the dependency if you specify `Remotes: url:://mywebsite.com/foo`.

If your code is in a Git repo (even if not on GitHub/GitLab) you can refer directly to the repo. Or if it's on a network drive you can refer to it using `local` instead of `url`, since `remotes::install_local` can handle directories.

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't on a local drive. It's an IP address I can map to a network drive (indeed, I already do), but then anyone else at the firm who wants to use the package  will also need to do so. So I guess that means a zipped file (or tarball) will be necessary... bugger.